# Example of a linear algebraic group which is not a Lie group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, lie-groups

I am trying to reconcile the notions of algebraic groups, linear algebraic groups, Lie groups, and Lie algebras, along with their notions of root systems, maximal tori, etc. To begin, I am trying to draw a sort of Venn diagram relating algebraic groups, linear algebraic groups, and Lie groups. Certainly all linear algebraic groups are algebraic groups. I know that the universal cover of $SL(2, \mathbb{R})$ is an example of a Lie group which is not a linear algebraic group.

Are all linear algebraic groups Lie groups? I know that they can all be realized as subgroups of some $GL(n, k)$, which is a Lie group, but I believe that a subgroup of a Lie group must be closed to be a Lie group itself.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: They're always smooth, so I don't see an obstruction to turning them into manifolds really. But I'm mostly thinking over $\mathbf{C}$ so this might be misleading.

Comment: A Lie subgroup $H$ is only required to be a subset of a Lie group $G$ such that the inclusion map from $H$ to $G$ is an injective immersion and group homomorphism.

Comment: Please, write down the definition of an algebraic group that you are using. Do you mean the set of real points of a group scheme defined over the real numbers? (One can talk about algebraic groups in relation to any field, say, p-adic numbers, which will make $Q_p$ and algebraic group which is not a Lie group.)

Comment: Yes, they can be realized as Zariski closed subgroups of some $GL(n,k)$. Thus they are closed so also Lie groups. It's the other way around ( as you pointed out) that is not true.

Comment: @studiosus: I was taking algebraic groups to be algebraic varieties which are also groups and such that the group multiplication is given by morphisms of varieties. I realize algebraic groups may not be Lie groups (as in your example) but I am looking at linear algebraic groups (where the underlying variety is affine). Thanks!

Comment: @orangeskid: Thank you! I was missing the Zariski closed part. Do you know of a reference for that fact?

Comment: @Tarnation: No worries! Books on algebraic groups 1. Humphreys, 2. Springer 3. Algebraic Geometry IV: Linear Algebraic Groups, Invariant Theory 4. Lie Groups and Algebraic Groups by Onishchik & Vinberg

Comment: @Tarnation: So the result is: an affine algebraic group ( the underlying variety is affine) is linear. Humphreys does it.

Comment: It's worth noting that over fields of positive characteristic the notion of a Lie group doesn't make any sense.  So any such linear algebraic group is an example of a linear algebraic group which is not a Lie group.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is mentioned in the comments, but it is my belief that answers to questions should be in the answer section.

If you look at the Wikipedia article on [linear algebraic groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_algebraic_group) you'll see they are defined to be (in different terms than they use, but better suited to the discussion) Zariski closed subgroups of the group of invertible $n\times n$ matrices. Over the real or complex numbers, this implies that they are closed in the usual topology on this Lie group. Being a closed subgroup of a Lie group, such a group is itself a Lie group. So all linear algebraic groups are Lie groups over a field for which the general linear group is a Lie group. In fields where the general linear group is not a Lie group (for example over $\mathbb Q$) a linear algebraic group need not be Lie group, so there is an example. However it still may be, for example if it has the discrete topology.

Comment: So if $F$ is an algebraic closure of the field $\Bbb{F}_p$ how do you give the group $SL_n(F)$ the structure of a differentiable manifold?

Comment: @Jyrki I specified this is over the real or complex numbers.

Comment: @Jyrki I put in a more complete answer.